# Proving the projection theorem in Hilbert spaces with an explicit formula for nearest element

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $S$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Let $\{e_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $S$, which exists as $S$ is separable. Is it true to say that the unique closest element of $f\in H$ in $S$ is $\sum \langle f,e_i\rangle e_i$. If so, can't we just take the above form of $g_0$ and use it to prove the projection theorem instead of creating a Cauchy sequence to the closest element?

Comment: $\sum_i \langle, e_i\rangle e_i$ is a Cauchy sequence. And the argument works whether $S$ is separable or not because a maximal orthonormal subset exists for $S$ whenever $S$ is a closed subset of a Hilbert space. Older presentations used to focus almost exclusively on orthonormality. However, it is easier to show that $\{ x_n\}$ is Cauchy whenever it is chosen to satisfy $\mbox{dist}(x_n,S) < \mbox{dist}(x,S)+1/n$, which leads to a "constructive" method of finding a unique closest point to $x$ in $S$, regardless of whether or not $S$ has a countable orthonormal basis.

Comment: $f $is EQUAL to $\sum_i<f,e_i>e_i$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Not here. The vectors $e_i$ are an ONB for $S$, not for the entire space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to prove the existence and uniqueness of the closest element by writing $g=\sum \langle f, e_i\rangle e_i$ and then using the fact that $(g-f)\perp S$ to show $g$ is closest. But this still has drawbacks:

1. One has to show the sum converges. When the space is not assumed separable, even the meaning of such convergence needs a discussion. (On the other hand, this discussion needs to happen at some point anyway.)
2. The argument is special to Hilbert spaces. In contrast, the approach based on picking a minimizing sequence and showing that it's Cauchy easily generalizes to every *uniformly convex* Banach space.